# Kafka gives LeaderNotFound Exception

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka application in NodeJS. I run that application in my local machine which was absolutely fine. I setup the same application on my production server. I have started Kafka and zookeeper by using init.d. After 3 days, kafka gives me an exception 'LeaderNotFound'. I tried to regenerate this error on my local machine and I observe that when I delete /tmp/kafka-logs/broker0 then this error happens. I have few topics in Kafka that have the same configuration as topic 'impression' below:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic impression
```

I solve this issue on my local system by changing the server, I mean I made another broker named server-1.properties and run it. All was fine after that but I donot think so that it is correct solution. Can you please guide me that how to get rid of this issue.

Exception which I am getting is :

```
[grunt-develop] > Events are sending to Kafka producer......

[grunt-develop] > Events are consumed by Kafka consumer......

[grunt-develop] > EventType in Consumer:click

[grunt-develop] > Incrementing sdk-server.apps.5637.requests.click

[grunt-develop] > Incrementing sdk-server.servers.ubuntu.requests.click

[grunt-develop] > POST /api/track/clk 200 116.987 ms - 68

[grunt-develop] > [ 'LeaderNotAvailable' ]

[grunt-develop] > Sent Event:click to Kafka!

[grunt-develop] > undefined

[grunt-develop] > events.js:74

[grunt-develop] >         throw TypeError('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');

[grunt-develop] > ^
[grunt-develop] > TypeError: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
    at TypeError (<anonymous>)
    at emit (events.js:74:15)
    at /home/asif/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/consumer.js:120:29
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/asif/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:387:24)
    at Client.handleReceivedData (/home/asif/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:563:18)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/asif/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:534:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
>> application exited with code 8
```

When I tries with Producer console, the results are below: (It is about topic 'click' same configuration as impression)

```
/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:92 --topic click
[2015-09-02 09:05:54,379] WARN Property topic is not valid (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
hello from click
[2015-09-02 09:06:03,733] WARN Error while fetching metadata    partition 0 leader: none    replicas:   isr:    isUnderReplicated: false for topic partition [click,0]: [class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException] (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-09-02 09:06:03,763] WARN Failed to collate messages by topic,partition due to: No leader for any partition in topic click (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2015-09-02 09:06:03,876] WARN Error while fetching metadata    partition 0 leader: none    replicas:   isr:    isUnderReplicated: false for topic partition [click,0]: [class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException] (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-09-02 09:06:03,878] WARN Failed to collate messages by topic,partition due to: No leader for any partition in topic click (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2015-09-02 09:06:03,983] WARN Error while fetching metadata    partition 0 leader: none    replicas:   isr:    isUnderReplicated: false for topic partition [click,0]: [class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException] (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-09-02 09:06:03,985] WARN Failed to collate messages by topic,partition due to: No leader for any partition in topic click (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2015-09-02 09:06:04,091] WARN Error while fetching metadata    partition 0 leader: none    replicas:   isr:    isUnderReplicated: false for topic partition [click,0]: [class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException] (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-09-02 09:06:04,094] WARN Failed to collate messages by topic,partition due to: No leader for any partition in topic click (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2015-09-02 09:06:04,201] WARN Error while fetching metadata    partition 0 leader: none    replicas:   isr:    isUnderReplicated: false for topic partition [click,0]: [class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException] (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2015-09-02 09:06:04,206] ERROR Failed to send requests for topics click with correlation ids in [0,8] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2015-09-02 09:06:04,208] ERROR Error in handling batch of 1 events (kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread)
kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:90)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:88)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:68)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:594)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are passing incorrect value for

> **--broker-list localhost:92**

Please provide a valid **PORT** and **HOSTNAME**, it should work.